# Compilation errors when declaring arrays with nil default values

Tags: swift

i am encountering weird error messages i cannot make sense of when declaring arrays with nil declare values.

I am doing this in Xcode playground.

```
//this is ok
var threeDoubles = [Double](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0.0)

//error: incorrect argument label in call, have count expected "arrayLiteral"
var threeDoubles2 = [Double](count: 3)

//error: extra argument "repeatedValue" in call
var threeDoubles2 = [Double](count: 3, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found my own bug. Basically, the values cannot be nil because I declared the array as *Double*, and not *Double?*

It has nothing to do with an extra argument, which was what xcode was showing me.

```
var threeDoubles2 = [Double?](count: 3, repeatedValue: nil)
```

The arcane error messages can really throw you off course even for simple errors.

Comment: Using the `[Type]()` syntax for initialization when you’re supplying parameters looks kind of odd to me tbh.  You could also try `var threeDoubles2 = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: nil as Double?)` or `var threeDoubles3: [Double?] = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: nil)` or `var threeDoubles3 = Array<Double?>(count: 3, repeatedValue: nil)`.